# How to enable WiFi while using two wireless cards one in monitor mode and other in managed mode?

Tags: wifi, monitoring, aircrack-ng

I have two wireless adapters, one is internal PCI wireless adapter (`wlan0`) while other is USB wireless adapter (`wlan1`).
I put `wlan0` in `monitor` mode and `wlan1` is in managed mode. But, after running

```
ifconfig wlan0 down 
iwconfig wlan0 mode Monitor 
ifconfig wlan0 up
sudo airodump-ng wlan0       //???
```

`wlan0` goes successfully in `monitor` mode but I lost internet connection. When I use

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

then `wlan0` switched back to `managed` mode.
Is there any way to put `wlan0` in `monitor` mode while keeping `wlan1` in `managed` mode and not loosing WiFi connection?

Answer (score 2):

You could do it all more "manually" :

Set your wlan0 interface down :
`ip link set wlan0 down`.

Change the mode from managed to monitor :
`iw dev wlan0 set type monitor`.

And bring back up :
`ip link set wlan0 up`.

And you can check the result with a simple `iw dev`.

That shouldn't change anything on your other interface wlan1, at least it does it for me (Debian 8). I don't know why you lose connection when launching airmon-ng start but I never managed to use it correctly, hence these 3 commands above...

Comment: I tried this `ifconfig wlan0 down
iwconfig wlan0 mode Monitor
ifconfig wlan0 up` and it worked until I ran the command `sudo airodump-ng mon0`. Now Internet is gone.

Comment: You have two 'real' interfaces, wlan0 and wlan1. mon0 is created by airmon-ng in our case here. Your problem is quite strange and as I said, I never use airmon-ng as I always failed to do anything with it, finding myself left with a virtual interface mon0 and as well, losing my connection. I use my 3 commands I wrote above and then launch `airodump-ng wlan0`. Now, you say internet is gone, or maybe your wifi connection from wlan1 ? (`ip a` : any ip assigned to wlan1?)

Comment: Yes, my WiFi is gone from wlan1. Before running `airodump-ng wlan0` I wan connected with WiFI through wlan1.

Comment: Could you go through the whole process again ? Starting with only wlan0/1 (no mon0, remove it), to point out when *exactly* you lose the connection. I understand clearly what you want since I had the same problem (an interface for airodump and other for internet), and I only managed to do so with manually setting the monitor mode. Another thing that you could try : instead of running `sudo service network-manager restart`, you could always set up in managed mode wlan1, release whatever you have for dhcp : `dhclient -r wlan1` and ask for an ip : `dhclient wlan1`, and leave your wlan0 alone!

Comment: I edited the question and removed `mon0`. Now forget `airmon`. I loose connection when I run `airodump-ng wlan0`. `wlan1` is in `managed` mode and was connected to WiFi before losing the connection.

Comment: I just followed the same steps as you, using a miserable Broadcom BCM433x for internal wifi device and a USB tp link and I had no problem. If I recall right, I had had losses of connection some time ago with Broadcom badly supported devices on Debian when trying what you do. If you lose connection just after launching `airodump-ng wlan0`, I can only suggest to look for some sort of logs and eventually, switch between wlan0 and wlan1 just for the try...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38739/discussion-between-bamse-and-haccks).